# AngularJS create dynamic template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I´m currently trying to create some kind of dynamic template, which fetches data and meta information from two separate services. The final result should be an table showing the data with the correct labels. My plan was to create `HTML`-templates with different basic designs like a table with 3,4 or 5 columns. Then a matching controller should fetch the meta data from a service which should return an array with the `id` of an attribute and its `name` which should be displayed in the table. So far so good but now comes the tricky part:
The second service fetches the matching data for the template and the `id` of the meta data and the `id` of the actual data matches, so that you can match them correctly.

Here is the Code on plunkr: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8162/)

The Main problem is the following piece of code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <td>{{person.name}}</td> 
   <td>{{person.age}}</td>
   <td>{{person.postal}}</td>
</tr>
```

In between the `<td>`-tags the data doesn´t get fetched dynamic but static. I don´t want to explicitly say how my attributes are called but use the fetched data from the meta service to know how my attributes are called.
So in the end the template should get the names of the attributes as well as the matching data. Do you guys have any good idea for me how to solve this?

**EDIT**
To make things a little more clear:
At the moment the data between the `<td>` tags is fetched static because the term `{{person.name}}` stands there hard coded. Let´s assume that the structure of the data chenges and there will be a `country`-attribute instead of the `postal` one. The template which stays the same still tries to get data from `person.postal` and not from `person.country`. So `undefined` or even an error would be the consequence.
To prevent this the names of the attributes should get fetched from a meta service and build in the `HTML` page.

The workflow should look somehow like this:

1. fetch the metadata --> get the names of the attributes
2. Set the names of the attributes inside the 'HTML' to call the correct attribute
3. fetch the actual data with the attributes defined before
4. Create the table

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this: "In between the <td>-tags the data doesn´t get fetched dynamic but static"?

Comment: your fiddle contains error , update the code

Comment: @AnmolMittal I fixed the code. Also described my problem a little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lt024p9h/1/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
       <td ng-repeat="attr in query.attribs">
         {{person[attr.id]}}
       </td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</div>
```

Right so what is going on here?

So going by your fiddle, what we do if get the attributes you wish to display then using the object as an [associative array](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/).

This does require that the `attr.id` and the properties match up.